# python - choosing serial port

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

Using an Arduino to send data to a Raspberry Pi. While this is a project under development this might not be the real case for the end product. But I find myself swapping the USB cable from the Arduino back and fourth between my computer and the  RPI. On the RPI the port for the USB connection changes every time i take the cable in and out. Works like an increment. Now the port number is `ttyACM4`, but i started today at `ttyACM1`. Under `/dev/` all three previous connections `ttyACM1-3` are removed.

So, to be sure i use the correct serial port in my Python code, is there a way of making sure i'm using the correct port when starting my `serial.Serial`?

Well, is there an easier way of doing this as to holding the both hardware main application code and make a serial handshake, and have the RPI test all its connections available via `serial.tools.list_ports`?

Comment: I'd start with trying to get the device to have a stable name before cycling through all ports.  `udev` is the thing that names the dev nodes.  You can try to write your own rule for naming the serial port node, or there might already be a rule populating `/dev/serial/by-{id,path}/`, which might be stable enough for your purposes.  You probably need to close and reopen the port every time the device is reconnected.  If that doesn't work, try cycling through the ports.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/rules/60-serial.rules

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by checking the os for available ports, then used the first available as my serial port.  Your application may need some adjusting, as to which ports to check, and in what order to check them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,serial

#add ports you want to check to this list, in the order you want them checked:
serial_ports=['/dev/ttyUSB0','/dev/ttyUSB1','/dev/ttyACM0','/dev/ttyACM1']

serial_port=""
for x in serial_ports:
   #print 'trying ',x
   if os.popen('ls '+x+' >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?').read().strip()=='0':
      serial_port=x   
      break;         #stop checking, we found one

#if you want to see all ports available, you need to adjust the code here 
#and make a decision as to which port to use

baud=9600
if len(serial_port)>1:
   self.ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud, timeout=0)
else:
   print 'No serial ports found'
```